# Akka EventHandler spinning forever. How should I stop it?

Tags: scala, event-handling, akka

I think I found a problem with the `EventHandler`. The below spec will run forever.
Basically the `EventHandler.info()` will cause this. I tried calling `EventHandler.shutdown()` using the After spec. But, without luck. Do you think I'm missing something?

Akka: 1.3-RC1

```scala
class EventHandlerProblem extends Specification {

  def is =
    "This describes a possible problem with the EventHandler" ^
      p ^
      "The EventHandler should" ^
      "not keep spinning forever...." ! e1

  end

  def e1 = {
    // no need to start the actor
    val ac = TestActorRef[PrintMessageActor]

    true must beTrue
  }
}

class PrintMessageActor extends Actor {
  EventHandler.info(this, "Printer actor is starting up...")

  def receive = {
    case msg => {
      println("Recieved: " + msg)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Akka Actor tests, I have a special trait which calls the `registry.shutdownAll` after running all of the fragments.  This way, while you still need to be careful that your tests can run in parallel without stepping on each other, things get cleaned up after all the tests run.  Here's the trait:

```
import org.specs2.Specification
import org.specs2.specification.{Step,Fragments}
import akka.actor.Actor.registry
trait AkkaSpec extends Specification {
  override def map(fs: => Fragments) = fs ^ Step(registry.shutdownAll)
}

class EventHandlerProblem extends AkkaSpec {

  def is =
    "This describes a possible problem with the EventHandler" ^
      p ^
      "The EventHandler should" ^
      "not keep spinning forever...." ! e1

  end

  def e1 = {
    // no need to start the actor
    val ac = TestActorRef[PrintMessageActor]

    true must beTrue
  }
}

class PrintMessageActor extends Actor {
  EventHandler.info(this, "Printer actor is starting up...")

  def receive = {
    case msg => {
      println("Recieved: " + msg)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I used this solution. But I added an additional call to Actor.remote.shutdown() otherwise it won't work (at least it's required on the project I'm working on).

NOTE: notice that you won't notice this on SBT. Only if you run it with an IDE you'll see it. Of course, you can always perform a thread dump...

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `EventHandler.shutdown()` and it worked properly (without hanging up).
Here is output:

```
Testing started at 11:03 ...
[INFO]    [29/11/11 11:03] [specs2.DefaultExecutionStrategy1] [PrintMessageActor] Printer actor is starting up...
[INFO]    [29/11/11 11:03] [specs2.DefaultExecutionStrategy2] [PrintMessageActor] Printer actor is starting up...
Process finished with exit code 0
```

And code:

```
import akka.testkit.TestActorRef
import org.specs2.Specification
import akka.event.EventHandler

class EventHandlerProblemSpec extends Specification {

  def is =
    "This describes a possible problem with the EventHandler" ^
      p ^
      "The EventHandler should" ^
      "not keep spinning forever...." ! e1 ^
      "not keep spinning forever 2...." ! e2 ^
      end

  def e1 = {
    {
      val ac = TestActorRef[PrintMessageActor]
      true must beTrue
    } after {
      EventHandler.shutdown()
    }
  }

  def e2 = {
    try {
      val ac = TestActorRef[PrintMessageActor]
      true must beTrue
    } finally {
      EventHandler.shutdown()
    }
  }
}
```